# How to make Google Tag Manager Tag , run before html content shows up?

Tags: jquery, css, triggers, google-tag-manager

I'm working on GTM to change the style of a cloud application.
obviously, I don't have access to the core files of this app & I just want using GTM to change some CSS stuff before the old design appears to my clients.

I tried Page View Trigger on All Pages OR Page View Trigger with Page URL Contain Filter. it is working fine, but the problem is clients see the old design appear and get change very quickly. (1-2 second delay).

I want to remove this small delay and stop/hide the old design/content to appear. But I Don't know what triggers or events should I use for this to achieve.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work as is indeed the reason Google recommends not to use GTM for tags that change the layout, force repaints etc. ([as they say](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2787990?hl=en&ref_topic=2772416), "tags that are associated with in-page structure"). A tag that changes CSS would need to fire reliably in a synchronous manner before anything else loads and GTM simply does not do that.

A workaround that is used e.g. when deploying A/B-Tests via GTM is to have a body class in the application files that hides the body and have GTM un-hide it after it made changes to the page layout, but that would require at least one-time access to the page code.

So it seems you are out of luck for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach that Google Optimize page-hiding snippet. It temporarily hide the page while you are changing your DOM or CSS.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/pagehiding